# Run Angular Universal app with different env

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have this script in `package.json` :

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json -c=dev",
    "start:dev": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json -c=dev",
    "start:test": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json  -c=test",
    "build": "ng build -c=dev",
    "build:dev": "ng build -c=dev",
    "build:test": "ng build -c=test",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run eb-desktop-app:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/eb-desktop-app/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run eb-desktop-app:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run eb-desktop-app:prerender"
},
```

As you can see, I have 2 environmets: dev and test. I can choose which environment I want for start or build commands (using `-c=env` flag), but how can I change environment for Universal script commands like  `npm run dev:ssr` ? when I add `-c=test` flag it says : `An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'test' is not set in the workspace.`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you have `test` and a `dev` configurations specified for the `serve-ssr` target in your `angular.json` file. You probably only have them for the `build` and `serve` targets for now

```
"serve-ssr": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "eb-desktop-app:build",
        "serverTarget": "eb-desktop-app:server"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "eb-desktop-app:build:production",
          "serverTarget": "eb-desktop-app:server:production"
        },
        "test": {
          "browserTarget": "eb-desktop-app:build:test",
          "serverTarget": "eb-desktop-app:server:test"
        },
        "dev": {
          "browserTarget": "eb-desktop-app:build:dev",
          "serverTarget": "eb-desktop-app:server:dev"
        }
      }
    },
```